# A C function that compares between operators

Tags: c

Is there a function in C that receives mathematical operators as characters and returns whichever operator should be used first, or a function that receives two operators and returns 1 or 0 if a certain operator should come before the other ?

Specifically, the mathematical operators I am talking about are ^, *, /, + and -. I need to be able to determine which should go first into a stack of operators (or wait). The only thing that I can think of is writing 5-10 different functions that address every case very specifically.

Comment: You get to write that yourself.  Give it a try. It's not very hard.

Comment: If you have the input as chars func('+', '-') etc you would certainly be able to write one, but if would want a func(+, -) I don't think you would be able to.

Comment: You are probably asking the wrong question (smells badly as an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)....). I guess you are coding some [parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing#Computer_languages), then you should tell which one or for which formal language.  So please **edit your question** to improve it a lot and motivate it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not as difficult to implement as it looks. Use constants or an `enum` to represent the specific operators, rather than working with the characters themselves. So, for example, `OP_PLUS=0, OP_MINUS=1...`

Then use a lookup table of some sort, or just a plain function containing a `switch()`, that gets the precedence of each operator, as a number from (say) zero to five. So, in a sense, implement this function:

```
int get_precedence (Operator my_operator) {...}
```

where "Operator" is the `enum` that lists the different operator values. Then comparing whether one operator has a higher precedence than another simply amounts to calling get_priority() on each one, and seeing which is higher.

A quick and dirty way to achieve a similar objective is to assign numbers to each operator, such that the numbers are assigned *in order of precedence*. So to compare precedence all you have to do is compare the numbers the represent the operators. But I suspect this will lead to code that is hard to understand and maintain.

The key to any of these approaches is to assign a number (enum, constant, whatever) to represent each operator, and pass those numbers around, rather than character values.